# Append a value at the end of a row of a text file through Siebel escript

Tags: siebel

My requirement is as follows.

In step 1 my business service will read the records from a text file.
In step 2 they create a record based on the values.
In step 3 it has to append a Success/Failure message at the end of the corresponding record.

Text file will contain multiple records, each field is delimited with '|'. So my requirement is to append Success/Failure after the last value of the record.

Please help.

Comment: A good point to start would be the Siebel bookshelf. Specifically, the [Clib file input and output methods](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/eScript/C_Language_Reference18.html#wp1300771) chapter from the [eScript language reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/eScript/eScriptTOC.html) book.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can have a look at this code. 
This code reads data from a Excel Sheet and creates record in Siebel BC. You can implement this as part of a BS. You can also extend this and add logic to include Success or Failure message in each record.

```
if (MethodName == "ImportRecords") 
{ 
    var i =2; 
    var ExcelApp = COMCreateObject("Excel.Application"); 
    ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\***\\***\\Desktop\\LoadTest.xlsx"); 
    ExcelApp.Visible = false; 
    var oBOLdVal = TheApplication().GetBusObject("Dummy BO"); 
    var oBCLdVal = oBOLdVal.GetBusComp("Dummy BC"); 
    while(ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,1).Value!= null) 
    { 
        var A= ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,1).Value; 
        var B= ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,2).Value; 
        var C= ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,3).Value; 
        var D= ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,4).Value; 
        var E= ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,5).Value; 
        with(oBCLdVal) 
        { 
            ActivateField("A"); 
            ActivateField("B"); 
            ActivateField("C"); 
            ActivateField("D"); 
            ActivateField("E"); 
            ClearToQuery();  
            InvokeMethod("SetAdminMode","TRUE"); 
            NewRecord(NewAfter); 
            SetFieldValue("A",A); 
            SetFieldValue("B",B); 
            SetFieldValue("C",C); 
            SetFieldValue("D",D); 
            SetFieldValue("E",E); 
            SetFieldValue("Status","Success"); 
            WriteRecord(); 
        } i=i+1; 
    } ExcelApp.Quit(); 
    ExcelApp = null; 
    oBOLdVal = null; 
    oBCLdVal = null; 
    TheApplication().RaiseErrorText("Load Success"); 
    return(CancelOperation); 
}
```

Hope this helps!